# Is there a taxonomy behind the tags to be assigned to the questions?

Tags: support, tags, tag-hierarchy

I need to know if there is a taxonomy or ontology (or concept net) behind the tags that are assigned to the questions people ask.
My goal is ultimately to facilitate a "topic extraction" process on the Stack Exchange Data for a machine learning task.

Comment: Do you mean some sort of hierarchy to the tags?

Comment: Tags are chosen by the people who post or edit questions based on what the question is about.

Comment: ...and then possibly changed by other users...

Comment: @Won't A.Lear stated that.

Comment: @nicael ... ... .......yeahbutstill

Answer (score 10):

No, tags are not created nor managed in any type of grouped ontology or hierarchical taxonomy. Tags are an *ad hoc* selection of "keywords" which are added by the author based on the subject space(s) encompassed by the question, and generally adhere to a lose set of conventions crowd-sourced by the community.